# excel auto fill date based on current date

Tags: vba, excel

I need to auto fill a specific column with a date. If the date occurs between Saturday through Tuesday, I need to auto fill the date column with the previous Friday. If the date occurs between Wednesday and Friday I need to put in the coming Friday date for the auto fill.

For example: If I run the spreadsheet on Tuesday 10/23 I need the auto fill date to be Friday 10/19. If I run the spreadsheet on Wednesday 10/24 I need the auto fill date to be Friday 10/26.

Here is the formula I have so far, so I need to invoke this formula via macro when saving the spreadsheet or by clicking a custom button. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A2),"",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())<4,(TODAY()+(-1-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))),(TODAY()+(6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using VBA for what you want, something like this which would go in the ThisWorkbook module and run prior to the workbook saving:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Check if A2 is blank
    If Cells(2, 1) = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Find the date and use it
    Dim x As Long
    Dim dateToUse As Date
    x = Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
    If x <= 4 Then
        dateToUse = Date - x
    Else
        dateToUse = Date + (7 - x)
    End If
    'Change Cells(1, 1) to the actual target you want to have the date, 
    'which could be determined based upon the contents of your workbook/sheet.
    Cells(1, 1) = dateToUse
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfect. But one more question, it is now only updating the specified cells address (Ex. (2,7)). How do I make the dateToUse value propaget to all the column 7 ((2,7),(3,7),(4,7) etc) till Cell (2,n) = "" (or end of the line)

Comment: Replace `Cells(1, 1)` with `Range(Cells(2,7),Cells(n,7))` where n is the last row number.

Comment: thanks daniel. I added this line to give me the last           rallLRall = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row          All works fine now. Thanks again.